# Multivariate normal expectation $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Hey I have two dimensional density :
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\sigma^{2}}}\exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2\left(1-\sigma^{2}\right)}\left(\begin{array}{c}
x^{2}+y^{2}-2\sigma xy\end{array}\right)\right\} $$

How to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2)$? I try from definition but the integrals are very strange. Is there any trick which can be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $X,Y$ are jointly standard gaussian with correlation coefficient $\rho$.  Thus it would be better to indicate your $\sigma^2$ as $\rho^2$.

Given this, your expectation is easy derived using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2|X)]=\mathbb{E}[X^2\mathbb{E}(Y^2|X)]$$

The quantity

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X]$$

is the conditional second moment...and it is well known how to factorize the joint density function

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(y|x)$$

into 2 gaussian densities in order to get it.

---

It results to me

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]=1+2\rho^2$$

... no integrals or weird calculations are needed.